Collatz's hypothesis || want to reuse code instead of repeating
I am trying to learn python and came across this Collatz's hypothesis where I need to
take any non-negative and non-zero integer number as input and if it's even, evaluate a condition
otherwise, if it's odd, evaluate another condition
if number ≠ 1, go back to even condition. I am checking same condition multiple times. Please guide me how to reuse the conditions without repeating them. Thank you in advance and my code is below.
"was trying to reduce input intakes and minimize condition check for one"
c0 = int(input("Enter a non-negative and non-zero integer number: "))
steps = 0
if c0 < 0:
    c0 = input("Enter a non-negative and non-zero integer number: ")
else:
    while c0 != 1:
        while c0 % 2 == 0 and c0 != 0:
            c0 /= 2
            steps += 1
            print(int(c0))
            if c0 == 1:
                break
        else:
            c0 = 3*c0 + 1
            steps += 1
            print(int(c0))
    else:
        print("steps = ", steps)


What do you mean by reuse the conditions? Could you be more specific if possible?

this book goes through the collatz conjecture in detail in python in the middle chapters:  python programming - collatz

The code seems to work. Maybe you want [codereview.se]

You should use a loop to keep repeating the input call until they enter a positive number; you currently allow them to enter a negative number the second time. Also, if c0 < 0: should be if c0 <= 0:. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response

Where do you repeat the same conditions?

There definitely is a cleaner way to write this code, but how do you expect to not 'reuse' the conditions? I'd assume the entire point of the 3x+1 conjecture is to 'reuse' the same conditions for each step, no? More info would be much appreciated.

You definitely don't need two loops. Loop while the number is not 1, yes, but inside the loop, the number is either even (in which case you divide by 2) or it isn't (in which case you triple and increment). IN either case, you increment step and evaluate the loop condition again.

Because you loop through it and regularly check for c0 being 1 and c0 not being 0, why not just use that as the while condition? Using it would make the break check unnecessary. Additionally, you don't need to use a while loop to check for even or odd numbers. Instead, you can use one while loop and conditionals inside.
Also, you check for < 0 instead of <= 0 in your first conditional. Additionally since c0 can never equal 0, you don't need to check for it in the loop.
c0 = int(input("Enter a non-negative and non-zero integer number: "))
steps = 0
if c0 <= 0: #Checks for negative or 0
    c0 = input("Enter a non-negative and non-zero integer number: ")
else:
    while c0 != 1: #Checks if c0 is 1. If so, print the steps and terminate
        if c0 % 2 == 0: #If c0 is even
            c0 /= 2
            steps += 1
            print(int(c0))
        else: #If c0 is odd
            c0 = 3*c0 + 1
            steps += 1
            print(int(c0))
    else:
        print("steps = ", steps)


This can be further improved by pulling the steps += 1 -- print(int(c0)) out of the if-else so they aren't repeated needlessly. Also, you can use the //= operator to do integer division so as to not have to deal with floats emerging from the division.

You are right, i should have used conditional  <= 0 at first instead i kept checking same since it loops inside when i used while loop , but not when using if. Thank you!

By utilizing Python 3.12.7.
Will this be helpful when using the walrus operator?
Snippet:
#c0 = int(input("Enter a non-negative and non-zero integer number: "))
steps = 0
if (c0 := int(input("Enter a non-negative and non-zero integer number: "))) < 0:
    #c0 = input("Enter a non-negative and non-zero integer number: ")
    print('hello')
else:
    while c0 != 1: #Checks if c0 is 1. If so, print the steps and terminate
        if c0 % 2 == 0: #If c0 is even
            c0 /= 2
            steps += 1
            print(int(c0))
        else: #If c0 is odd
            c0 = 3*c0 + 1
            steps += 1
            print(int(c0))
    else:
        print("steps = ", steps)

Output:
Enter a non-negative and non-zero integer number: 3
10
5
16
8
4
2
1
steps =  7

Enter a non-negative and non-zero integer number: -5
hello

Enter a non-negative and non-zero integer number: 4
2
1
steps =  2

Enter a non-negative and non-zero integer number: 6
3
10
5
16
8
4
2
1
steps =  8 


This can be further improved by pulling the steps += 1 -- print(int(c0)) out of the if-else so they aren't repeated needlessly. Also, you can use the //= operator to do integer division so as to not have to deal with floats emerging from the division.

Thank you , i was looking for operator like warlus so i can assign and use it as expression at same time so i dont need to repeat it using assign statement and conditional expression. But, for some reason i am getting invalid syntax when using warlus operator , i am using python 3.10

Upgrade Python 3.12.7 or wait for the next 3 days for Python 3.13.0

Search on website  walrtus python.  and PEP 572

Here is how I would approach your problem:

Basically I would suggest to remove while loops and use recursive function. This will simplify the code and will make it look cleaner.

c0 = 0
while c0<=0:
    try:
        c0 = int(input("Enter a non-negative and non-zero integer number: "))
    except:
        pass


def collatz_steps(c0: int) -> int:
    """ Returns number of steps. """
    print(c0)
    if c0==1:
        # return number of steps
        return 0
    
    if c0 % 2 == 0:
        # even number
        return 1+collatz_steps(c0//2)
    
    # odd number
    return 1+collatz_steps(c0*3+1)
    
steps = collatz_steps(c0)
print(steps)


Thank you for your time, I am unable to comprehend how steps are calculated in your code. I used pythontutor code visualizer to see step by step and it is showing me that it is storing each returned step value inside collatz_steps (c0) and counting from backwards of each returned step value.  Is there any reference I can follow to understand that codeflow for it. Waiting for your reply!

This is recursive approach to calculating steps. Let's say that you have c0 and function that should return number of steps f_steps(c0). Then for example if you have even c0 this function is equal to f_steps(c0) = 1 + f_steps(c0/2) and similar for odd c0.

but ultimately when it becomes 1 either way you are making it return 0, I am not able to understand why it doesn't return 0 in the end when it becomes 1 but it returns number of steps, like how it is able to go to even and odd conditions backwards and return steps, I haven't learned deeps into functions yet. so any reference for understanding would be great if you can
